# Why does equal values of variables give the maximum/minimum of a symmetric expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, maxima-minima

In questions related to maximum/minimum value of symmetric expressions, I have noticed that most of them can be done by placing the values of the variables as equal.

Examples of this fact range from simple AM-GM inequalities to this [IMO 1984 problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245030/imo-1984-prove-that-0-%E2%89%A4-yz-zx-xy-%E2%88%922xyz-%E2%89%A4-frac-727-where-x-y-and-z)

What I want to know is that is this fact some coincidence or is there some Mathematical law governing it?

Comment: It is not true in general. Loosely, if a function is convex then the $\min$ will occur at a symmetric point.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581849/do-symmetric-problems-have-symmetric-solutions