# Find minimum value of the function $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ on the ball $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$. (Where did I make a mistake?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Find minimum value of the function $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ on the ball $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$, where $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $a>0.$

What I did: 
Lagrange function: 
$L(x,y,z)=x+y+z+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2)$. 
$L_x=1+2\lambda x = 0.$ 
$L_y=1+2\lambda y = 0.$ 
$L_z=1+2\lambda z=0.$ 
$L_{\lambda}=x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$. 

From the first three equations: $x=y=z=-\frac{1}{2\lambda}$ 
From the last equation: 
$\frac{3}{4\lambda^2}=a^2 \Longrightarrow\lambda=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2a}$. 
Since we want $x,y,z\ge0.$ 
$x=y=z=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$ (Took the negative $\lambda$). 
And substituting back into $f(x,y,z)=\frac{3a}{\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{3}a$. 
But the answer is $a$. 
Would appreciate any help, I can't find where did I make a mistake, and I don't want to assume that the final answer given is false without being sure about it, because I know I make alot of mistakes. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer $a$ is false, your answer is correct.

Comment: Since $f\left(\sqrt{\frac a3},\sqrt{\frac a3},\sqrt{\frac a3}\right)=\sqrt3\,a>a$, and since $\left(\sqrt{\frac a3}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{\frac a3}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{\frac a3}\right)^2=a$, the correct answer cannot possibly be $a$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, the answer is correct. The minimum is indeed $a$. Here below is my answer. What the OP calculated is the maximum.

Comment: @NN2 Right. Nice answer. (+1)

Comment: In a closed interval, always remember that the max / min can happen on the boundary and Lagrange Multiplier method may not even identify that. Please see this answer if it helps - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142868/using-lagrange-multiplier-to-find-global-maximum-of-a-bounded-function

Comment: Thanks everyone! And @MathLover you do read my mind, you just answered my question that I asked to NN2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you found is the maximum of $f$ (more precisely, you found a critical point and this critical point is the maximum point of $f$) and not the minimum of $f$.

If you use Lagrange multipliers to find the minimum, you should study several cases: $(x,y,z) \in  (\Bbb R^+)^{3}$, $(x,y,z)$ on the border of $(\Bbb R^+)^{3}$ (this means for example $(x,y,z= (0,y,z)$,...). And the minimum point lies on the border of $(\Bbb R^+)^{3}$

But there exists a much simpler solution: we notice that $x(a-x) \ge 0$, then

$$x(a-x) + y(a-y)+z(a-z) \ge 0 $$
$$\implies a(x+y+z) \ge x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$$
$$\implies x+y+z \ge a$$

The equality occurs if and only if $(x,y,z) = (0,0,a), (0,a,0)$ or $(a,0,0)$

Q.E.D

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! I don't quite understand why does this happen? if what I have found are all the points which might be maximum minimum of the function on the ball, then why is the minimum doesn't have any relation with them? I thought since I have found two points, and they asked for a point with two positive values, I had one point which satisfy that, and was sure it must be the minimum. Plus what made me a little sure is the ball is a closed region, so the minimum or maximum must be on it. And I'm surprised why I didnt get the $a$ using lagrange multipliers..

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, if you want to use Lagrange multipliers method, you should study $4$ cases: $(x,y,z)$ all strictly positive and 3 other cases on the boundary (example: $x = 0$ and $(y,z)$ are positives,... ).  If not, Lagrange multipliers method doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks alot! Now when I drew the part of the ball, I understand what you meant, but I still got a question if possible: so when I did lagrange multipliers for all $x,y,z$ greater than zero, I missed out on the $3$ curves (\frac{1}{4} Circles) in xy, xz, yz planes, and in order to check them I can use lagrange multipliers too for each one and then compare all my results to find the minimal value? ( I can understand your brilliant answer but I don't think I will be able to notice such a thing myself)

Comment: @Pwaol Exactly, you should apply the method for the 3 cases where $(x,y,z)$ lies on the 3 planes and then compare the results of 4 cases to find the minimum. In fact, Lagrange multipliers can be used only on closed regions (for example : $x\in (2,3))$ and not on open regions (for example: $x \in [2,3]$) .

Comment: @Pwaol If you do not have to use Lagrange Multiplier method, the simplest way to see it is that $(x+y+z)^2 \geq x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$ given $x, y, z \geq 0$ and hence $x + y + z \geq a$.